# rails gem Simple_form installation is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using rails 4.2.4 and I am trying to use simple_form

Right now my view gives the error:

```
undefined method `simple_form_for' for #<#<Class:0xbbc2748>:0xbbc1460>
```

Gem list returns a list of gems and it includes simple_form. I installed simple_form by typing `gem install simple_form`

```
$gem list
```

returns

```
simple_form (3.2.1)
```

I have also tried and got this:

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
Could not find generator 'simple_form:install'. Maybe you meant 'responders:install', 'rspec:install' or 'devise:install'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just installed it via `gem install` you didn't add it to your Rails application.  Instead, you need to add it to your `Gemfile`, look at [the documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#installation).

Gemfile:

`gem 'simple_form'`

Then run `bundle install` and continue with the installation from the Github page.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem.
But I putted a `gem 'simple_form'` in my Gemfile.
I fixed the problem with a `spring stop` command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to your Gemfile, and then bundle. Rails uses bundler for gem management, and will only include gems that are included in your Gemfile.